# Unit Testing for Marklogic

Tags: unit-testing, marklogic

We are looking for a framework to test our **MarkLogic XQuery code**.

We can see **MarkLogic/XQunit** is a good framework, but it does not have code coverage feature.

What is the best framework to write unit test cases for **MarkLogic XQuery**?

Answer (score 15):

Two unit test frameworks I've seen used in practice are [XRay](https://github.com/robwhitby/xray) and [Roxy Unit Test](https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki/Unit-Testing) (note that Roxy Unit Test is part of a larger project, consisting of the Roxy Deployer, MVC structure, and Unit Test; the Unit Test feature will be easiest to use if you're also using the Deployer). Roxy can test XQuery and Server-side JavaScript code.

I'm not aware of any tool that provides code coverage at this time.

Edit: Rob Rudin has made the Roxy Unit Test framework more accessible to gradle projects: https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-unit-test.

Edit 2: ml-unit-test now offers an experimental code-coverage feature

Comment: There is also xqtest https://github.com/irinc/xqtest. I do prefer Xray over xqtest and only use Roxy Unit testing when I'm already using roxy in my project.

Comment: xray has an experimental code coverage branch: https://github.com/robwhitby/xray/tree/v2.1